# Mirth Connect does reply/response back at all when connected through TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, hl7, mirth, mllp

I have requirement to connect to `Mirth/Rosetta (NextGen)` through `TCP` connection, in order to send `HL7` message an receive back response. Since this is my first time interaction with mirth, so I'm starting as test in order to get to know if it works.

**Problem:** When I try to send a random text to mirth, or even `MLLP HL7 message`, it doesn't respond at all. I'm using very basic `TCP` connection code *(as shown below)* in order to test connection. I'm expecting mirth to send ACK with error, or at least some error. But it stays blank when `stream.Read` line is executed.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("x.x.x.x", 1234);
var message = "HELLO MIRTH";
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);
data = new Byte[256];
while (true)
{
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    if (bytes > 0)
        break;
}
var responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
```

What's surprising is that when I send the same message from some `HAPI TestPanel` *(a test tool to connect/send message to through TCP)* it works fine and I receive response (as shown in following screenshot). This makes me think like there is something I'm missing. Even though my test code shown above works well if I connect it with my own TCP listener. But when it tries to connect with Mirth, it doesn't get any response.

[image: Message sent through test tool]

**Question:** is there anything special that I need to add in my TCP sender, in order to talk to TCP server of Mirth (or any HL7 standard TCP server)? If not, please guide me in this regards. I need to connect and get response back.

**Messages I tried:**

- "Hello World"
- "MSH|^~&|xyz|xyz|xyzz||20210224162555.3992||ADT^A28|13391074-7b39-42f7-b6bf-f174fb6e8231|P|2.5 ..."
- HL7 message enclosed in VT and FS CR tags

Answer (score 1):

Try out this on the Mirth Connect server receiving the message. Define a transformer step on the destination connector with the desired output/response format. If the desired response is the raw data then just have a Javascript transformer then call the in-built function connectorMessage.getRawData(). Finally, on the TCP listener, select the transformer name (created at the destination connector) in the item list under the response (just below the source queue).